# Why isn't sendKeys working on this Protractor script?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, automated-tests, protractor

Why isn't sendKeys working on this Protractor script?

Almost nothing I try to do in Protractor works, but this seems like it should be written right. What am I missing??

```
creditCardInformation = function (ccHolderName,ccNumber,ccExpirationDate,ccCvvCode,ccBillingAddress,ccBillingCity,ccBillingState,ccBillingCountry) {  
        // ### USER-DEFINED VARIABLES - Credit Card             
        var ccHolderName = 'Johann Sebastian';
        var ccNumber = '1111222233334444';
        var ccExpirationDate = '10/2020';
        var ccCvvCode = '896';
        var ccBillingAddress = '1313 Mockingbird Lane';
        var ccBillingCity = 'Chicago';
        var ccBillingState = 'IL';
        var ccBillingCountry = 'USA';
        // ### STATIC VARIABLES - Credit Card 
        var creditCardHolderName = element(by.model('cc.cardHolderName'));
        var creditCardNumber = element(by.model('cc.creditCardNumber'));
        var creditCardExpirationDate = element(by.model('cc.expiry'));
        var creditCardCvvCode = element(by.model('cc.cvv'));
        var creditCardBillingAddress = element(by.model('cc.billingAddress'));
        var creditCardBillingCity = element(by.model('cc.billingCity'));
        var creditCardBillingState = element(by.model('cc.billingState'));
        var creditCardBillingCountry = element(by.model('cc.billingCountry'));
        // ### STATIC FUNCTIONS - Credit Card   
        creditCardHolderName.sendKeys(ccHolderName);
        creditCardNumber.sendKeys(ccNumber);
        creditCardExpirationDate.sendKeys(ccExpirationDate);
        creditCardCvvCode.sendKeys(ccCvvCode);
        creditCardBillingAddress.sendKeys(ccBillingAddress);
        creditCardBillingCity.sendKeys(ccBillingCity);
        creditCardBillingState.sendKeys(ccBillingState);
        creditCardBillingCountry.sendKeys(ccBillingCountry);      
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/quantumspooky/86k6z9pt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to two people's downvotes without comments, I figured out what I was doing wrong here.

Instead of 
`creditCardInformation = function (ccHolderName,ccNumber,ccExpirationDate,ccCvvCode,ccBillingAddress,ccBillingCity‌​,ccBillingState,ccBillingCountry)`

I should have said `creditCardInformation: function(creditCardHolderName,creditCardNumber,creditCardExpirationDate,creditCa‌​rdCvvCode,creditCardBillingAddress,creditCardBillingCity,creditCardBillingState,c‌​reditCardBillingCountry)`